# Size of "long long" in 128-bit machine?

Tags: c, types, long-long

In a 128-bit RISC-V (or other 128-bit machine), how big are "long" and "long long" data types in C/C++?

To clarify: what are the sizes that an implementer of a compiler might be expected to use when writing the limits.h file for such a machine, in the absence of other implementations to conform to?

Answer (score 8):

They can be *any* size the compiler writer wanted, subject to them being at least as large as their predecessor type (`long int` for `long long int` and `int` for `long int`) and satisfying the minimum ranges set out in the standards.

See, for example, `5.2.4.2 Numerical limits` in C11, which states the *minimum* range required:

```
long int
    LONG_MIN           -2147483647 // −(2^31 − 1)
    LONG_MAX           +2147483647 //   2^31 − 1
long long int
    LLONG_MIN -9223372036854775807 // −(2^63 − 1)
    LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807 //   2^63 − 1
```

Note that these aren't your *full* two's complement range since they have to account for the other two encoding schemes as well, ones' complement and sign-magnitude, both of which have the concept of negative zero.

If you really want to know, you can just look up those values in the `limits.h` header file, or compile and run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {
    printf ("BITS/CHAR %d\n", CHAR_BIT);
    printf ("CHARS/SHORT %d\n", sizeof(short));
    printf ("CHARS/INT %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf ("CHARS/LONG %d\n", sizeof(long));
    printf ("CHARS/LLONG %d\n", sizeof(long long));
    putchar ('\n');

    printf ("SHORT MIN %d\n", SHRT_MIN);
    printf ("SHORT MAX %d\n", SHRT_MAX);
    printf ("INT MIN %d\n", INT_MIN);
    printf ("INT MAX %d\n", INT_MAX);
    printf ("LONG MIN %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
    printf ("LONG MAX %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
    printf ("LLONG MIN %lld\n", LLONG_MIN);
    printf ("LLONG MAX %lld\n", LLONG_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, a fairly bog-standard one (and slightly reformatted to look pretty):

```
BITS/CHAR      8
CHARS/SHORT    2
CHARS/INT      4
CHARS/LONG     4
CHARS/LLONG    8

SHORT MIN                 -32768
SHORT MAX                  32767
INT MIN              -2147483648
INT MAX               2147483647
LONG MIN             -2147483648
LONG MAX              2147483647
LLONG MIN   -9223372036854775808
LLONG MAX    9223372036854775807
```

So it looks like, on this system, I have two's complement (the `8/7` mismatch on the last digit of negative/positive numbers), no padding bits, 16-bit `short int`, 32-bit `int` and `long int` and 64-bit `long long int`.

If you run similar code in your own environment, that should be able to tell you similar information for it.

Comment: There is a second constraint on the size of `long long`: It must be at least 64 bits. That's guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: @cmaster: actually, the phrase "64 bits" is seen only thrice in C11, twice in relation to IEC 60559 floating point format and once for the exact-width integer types. It is not mentioned at all for the normal integer types though you could extrapolate the ranges (which *are* specified) to assume 64 bits are required. But it's the *ranges* that are mandated specifically rather than the width. Of course, I may be wrong, it wouldn't be the first time. But I'd need a citation of the standard to convince me :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The C11 defines _bit_ in §3.5 as unit, that is large enough to hold two values. It also mentions term _mathematically defined_ in §6.5/p5. By pure math, you can store exactly `2^n` unique values in `n`-bit entity, The _minimum_ range of `long long int` implies `abs(LLONG_MIN) + LLONG_MAX + 1` unique values (extra one for zero). Result of `ceil(log2(abs(LLONG_MIN) + LLONG_MAX + 1))` is 64, thus it's the _minimum_ width in bits for that type. Note that this is not neccesiraly implies eight bytes, since `CHAR_BIT` is implementation-defined and can be different from eight.

Comment: @Grzegorz, though I appreciate the effort, that seems like a huge amount of work (and implication) to deliver a piece of information that's pretty much useless, especially as you'd need to also take into account any padding bits may exist, further "disconnecting" the range from the width. I think I'll stick with the ranges since they deliver information that's of far more use :-)

Answer (score 0):

Include the limits.h header and print the size of the wanted type.

```
 #include <limits.h>

int main () {

printf ("Size of long long is :  %d\n", sizeof(long long));

return 0;
}
```